# How to fix strange behaviour input radio in a JS quiz game

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I'm trying to create a very basic JS quiz game. Almost everything works except for a single piece of code. When you hit the third radio input at the very last question, you have to double click the button in order to make true the "if else" statement. If I check the first two radio buttons everything works correctly. I don't understand why.

```js
// VARIABLES
    var all = {
        question: ['Quante dita ha una mano?', "Qual è la capitale del Marocco", "Cosa si mangia in Spagna?" ],
        response: [['uno', 'due', 'cinque'],['Marrakesh', 'Dubai', 'Roma'], ['Paella', 'Salsiccia', 'Fish']]
    }
    var i = 0;
    var storage = [];
    // TITLE
    var title = document.getElementById("title");
    //LABELS
    var label1 = document.getElementById('risposta1');
    var label2 = document.getElementById('risposta2');
    var label3 = document.getElementById('risposta3');
    // INPUTS
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')
    var input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
    var input2 = document.getElementById('input2');
    var input3 = document.getElementById('input3');
    
    // DISPLAY ANSWER
    function displayAnswer(){
        if(all.response[i] != undefined){
            title.innerHTML = all.question[i];
            label1.innerHTML = all.response[i][0];
            label2.innerHTML = all.response[i][1];
            label3.innerHTML = all.response[i][2];
        }
    }
    
    
    displayAnswer();
    
    document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener("click", function(e){
        inputs.forEach(function(input){
            if(i <= (all.question.length - 1)){
                if(input.checked === true){
                    console.log(e);
                    console.log(input3);
                    console.log(input.value);
                    storage.push(input.value);
                    i++;             
                    displayAnswer();
                    console.log(i);
                }
            } 
            else {
                console.log("Your score is: " + storage);
                document.getElementById( 'content' ).style.display = 'none';
            }
            
        })
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="content">
         <h1 id="title"></h1>
         <label id="risposta1"></label>    
         <input id="input1" type="radio" name="test"  value="1" ><br>
         <label id="risposta2"></label>  
         <input id="input2" type="radio" name="test"  value="2" ><br>
         <label id="risposta3"></label>  
         <input id="input3" type="radio" name="test"  value="3"> <br>
         <button id="btn">Invia</button>
     </div>
        
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

In the console there is no errors.

Comment: share your html also

Comment: Use [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to post your HTML and JavaScript and make it executable.

Comment: Why are you looping over all the radio buttons? You'll print the score 3 times.

Comment: You don't seem to have any way of telling if the button they checked is the correct answer to the quiz.

Comment: I want just to assign value based on the value input. There is no correct answer.